# Insert query from cell into MS access database is becoming comment if the cell contains (')

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert value from excel to database MS Access but if the cell value contains and special characters like comma (') it is reading the cell value and while executing the insert query after comma (') is commented in VBA.

Cell value contains 5500's application -- there is (') due to this further insert query after that is not considered as it is a commented.

Let me know how to handle this.

Is there any we can allow user to provide the symbol or we need to restrict him not enter such type of characters

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating your own SQL insert statement by concatenating strings together and then executing it.  e.g.

```
Dim SQL = "UPDATE titles SET type=" & type & " WHERE title_id =" & id
```

This is a big no no, You're setting yourself up for SQL Injection attacks and all sort of headaches

You need take it a step further and use prepared statements.   Refer to the code sample here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905910(v=sql.80).aspx